# Add cocos2d scene to UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I use the following code to add cocos2d scene to a viewcontroller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];


    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:CCDirectorTypeDefault];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setPixelFormat:kPixelFormatRGBA8888];

    [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];


    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] attachInView:self.view];
    ///adding HelloWorld scene to the view...
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [HelloWorld scene]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

And now i need to set the alpha value of self.view....so i did it..

```
-(void)displaySharePage
{
    self.view.alpha=0;

}
```

But it crashed......don't know why....i got the message..

> 'A Director was alloced.
>   setDirectorType must be the first call
>   to Director'

can anyone help.....advance thanks..

Comment: A few questions.  1.  Where are you calling the displaySharePage function in your program?  This could be the cause for your crash. 2.  Alpha value of a view is a CGFloat instance, you should be setting it as 0.0f.  This is a minor point however, don't suspect it will cause the crash but its good to eliminate any possiblities.  3.  Are you getting any warnings on compilation of your program?  If so what are they?  4.  Does the program run if you don't set the alpha value?

Comment: i call displaySharePage function from helloscene of cocos2d...the program run if i don't access view property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error, it looks like one of two things is happening:

1. `viewDidLoad` is being called more than once. You can check this by adding a log statement or breakpoint at the beginning of the method. This will help you find the root cause. You have to make sure that the director code is only called once. One way (not necessarily the right way) is to move the `[CCDirector setDirectorType:]` call to your app delegate.
2. You are calling `[CCDirector setDirectorType:]` somewhere else in your code. This seems unlikely, but doing a search for it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

attachInView will be deprecated. Try using `setOpenGLView` instead. http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_c_c_director.html#a87f9460b05b18b5c7726e1bdcbfe3eca

Answer (score 1):

[maybe its really getting called twice?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=569074)

Answer (score 1):

```
    @synthesize window;

- (void)loadView {
    // Initialization code
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    //landscape
    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];
    [director setDisplayFPS:YES];

    //turn on multi-touch
    EAGLView *cocosView = [director openGLView];
    [cocosView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    self.view = cocosView;

    //default texture formats...
    [CCTexture2D  setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:[MainGame scene]];
}
```